# Split audiobook on chapters with speech recognition

Tags: f#, speech-recognition

I'm looking to create a script that:

- can take in a single audiobook sound file
- find all instances that match the phrase "Chapter ##"
- split out the audiofile into multiple chapter files.

Currently, I have a script that is able to parse some of the words in the book, but it produces way too many false positives.

**Here is the script that I have come up with:**

```
#r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Speech.dll"

open System
open System.IO
open System.Speech.Recognition
open System.Speech.AudioFormat
open System.Linq
open System.Collections.Generic

let recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))

let numbers = ["Zero"; "One"; "Two"; "Three"; "Four"; "Five"; "Six"; "Seven"; "Eight"; "Nine"] |> Seq.map (fun x -> " Chapter " + x + " " ) |> Seq.toArray
let choices = new Choices()
choices.Add(numbers)   
let gb = new GrammarBuilder() 
gb.Append(choices)

recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(gb))
recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile(@"c:\temp\temp.wav")
recognizer.InitialSilenceTimeout <- TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0)
recognizer.BabbleTimeout <- TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0)
recognizer.EndSilenceTimeout <- TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0)
recognizer.EndSilenceTimeoutAmbiguous <- TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0)

recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)
recognizer.SpeechRecognized.Add(fun args -> printfn "Recognized [%f] '%s' '%s'" args.Result.Confidence args.Result.Text (args.Result.Audio.AudioPosition.ToString("c")))
recognizer.RecognizeCompleted.Add(fun args -> recognizer.Dispose())
```

**Which generates the following output for my test audiobook file:**

```
Recognized [0.768345] 'Chapter One' '00:00:00.6784580'
Recognized [0.875096] 'Chapter One' '00:00:06.0961451'
Recognized [0.924447] 'Chapter Zero' '00:00:12.4018140'
Recognized [0.859189] 'Chapter Two' '00:00:18.5877551'
Recognized [0.664151] 'Chapter Two' '00:00:23.2371882'
Recognized [0.946657] 'Chapter Nine' '00:00:28.4553287'
Recognized [0.955821] 'Chapter Four' '00:00:33.8530612'
Recognized [0.640227] 'Chapter Zero' '00:00:42.8526077'
Recognized [0.931088] 'Chapter Nine' '00:00:47.8911564'
Recognized [0.783337] 'Chapter Six' '00:00:51.7823129'
Recognized [0.653988] 'Chapter Zero' '00:00:55.9727891'
Recognized [0.732726] 'Chapter Five' '00:01:07.9356009'
Recognized [0.935443] 'Chapter Nine' '00:01:12.4253968'
Recognized [0.870314] 'Chapter Four' '00:01:17.9428571'
Recognized [0.651171] 'Chapter Seven' '00:01:27.8303854'
Recognized [0.922714] 'Chapter One' '00:01:37.0294784'
Recognized [0.684078] 'Chapter Seven' '00:01:42.4172335'
Recognized [0.942972] 'Chapter Zero' '00:01:47.8748299'
Recognized [0.829883] 'Chapter Two' '00:01:51.7959183'
Recognized [0.938676] 'Chapter Nine' '00:01:55.7668934'
Recognized [0.791102] 'Chapter Seven' '00:02:02.6213151'
Recognized [0.875539] 'Chapter Six' '00:02:07.1809523'
Recognized [0.639413] 'Chapter Five' '00:02:11.6308390'
Recognized [0.902068] 'Chapter Five' '00:02:22.1070294'
Recognized [0.910636] 'Chapter One' '00:02:26.4172335'
Recognized [0.630831] 'Chapter Six' '00:02:30.7573696'
Recognized [0.923125] 'Chapter Seven' '00:02:35.2172335'
Recognized [0.766578] 'Chapter Zero' '00:02:50.9215419'
Recognized [0.619602] 'Chapter One' '00:02:57.0077097'
Recognized [0.876517] 'Chapter Seven' '00:03:02.2857142'
Recognized [0.826771] 'Chapter Eight' '00:03:08.2222222'
Recognized [0.875892] 'Chapter One' '00:03:13.0911564'
Recognized [0.837238] 'Chapter Zero' '00:03:17.2018140'
Recognized [0.759909] 'Chapter Three' '00:03:22.0308390'
Recognized [0.939185] 'Chapter Five' '00:03:27.2789115'
Recognized [0.843361] 'Chapter Zero' '00:03:32.7265306'
Recognized [0.664468] 'Chapter Seven' '00:03:37.0766439'
Recognized [0.724578] 'Chapter Seven' '00:03:41.8757369'
Recognized [0.907078] 'Chapter Five' '00:03:47.0839002'
Recognized [0.824832] 'Chapter Seven' '00:03:51.1646258'
Recognized [0.823602] 'Chapter Two' '00:03:56.3229024'
Recognized [0.641332] 'Chapter Three' '00:04:00.6730158'
Recognized [0.870558] 'Chapter One' '00:04:06.3301587'
Recognized [0.883838] 'Chapter Seven' '00:04:12.3863945'
Recognized [0.674429] 'Chapter Five' '00:04:17.6843537'
Recognized [0.676834] 'Chapter Zero' '00:04:22.6031746'
Recognized [0.668765] 'Chapter Six' '00:04:28.4399092'
Recognized [0.918949] 'Chapter Four' '00:04:33.4285714'
Recognized [0.770719] 'Chapter Four' '00:04:37.1600907'
Recognized [0.886996] 'Chapter Four' '00:04:42.7573696'
Recognized [0.888173] 'Chapter One' '00:04:46.7582766'
Recognized [0.911851] 'Chapter Five' '00:04:51.6571428'
Recognized [0.640761] 'Chapter Seven' '00:04:57.7931972'
Recognized [0.739840] 'Chapter Three' '00:05:02.8217687'
Recognized [0.682130] 'Chapter Nine' '00:05:17.6081632'
Recognized [0.916081] 'Chapter Seven' '00:05:27.2662131'
Recognized [0.873457] 'Chapter Zero' '00:05:32.3546485'
Recognized [0.690658] 'Chapter Seven' '00:05:44.1877551'
Recognized [0.754081] 'Chapter Zero' '00:05:50.0643990'
Recognized [0.753562] 'Chapter Zero' '00:05:56.0308390'
Recognized [0.817155] 'Chapter Two' '00:06:01.9274376'
Recognized [0.928972] 'Chapter Eight' '00:06:06.5968253'
Recognized [0.767937] 'Chapter One' '00:06:12.3238095'
Recognized [0.944847] 'Chapter One' '00:06:17.0131519'
Recognized [0.684238] 'Chapter Nine' '00:06:34.5632653'
Recognized [0.790749] 'Chapter Six' '00:06:38.3945578'
Recognized [0.620242] 'Chapter Six' '00:06:43.9718820'
Recognized [0.844388] 'Chapter Eight' '00:06:54.0190476'
Recognized [0.731784] 'Chapter Eight' '00:06:58.2893424'
Recognized [0.631801] 'Chapter Zero' '00:07:12.4272108'
Recognized [0.721280] 'Chapter One' '00:07:18.4834467'
Recognized [0.826446] 'Chapter Seven' '00:07:22.8934240'
Recognized [0.704257] 'Chapter Seven' '00:07:27.1437641'
Recognized [0.857281] 'Chapter Zero' '00:07:32.4716553'
Recognized [0.724900] 'Chapter Zero' '00:07:37.8394557'
Recognized [0.706603] 'Chapter Four' '00:07:42.8780045'
Recognized [0.767831] 'Chapter One' '00:07:50.2712018'
Recognized [0.868492] 'Chapter One' '00:07:55.7487528'
Recognized [0.775758] 'Chapter Seven' '00:07:59.7197278'
Recognized [0.911844] 'Chapter One' '00:08:04.8081632'
Recognized [0.828079] 'Chapter Three' '00:08:09.9165532'
Recognized [0.872625] 'Chapter One' '00:08:14.0471655'
Recognized [0.876143] 'Chapter Three' '00:08:17.9383219'
Recognized [0.667334] 'Chapter Three' '00:08:21.7396825'
Recognized [0.835629] 'Chapter Zero' '00:08:30.7591836'
Recognized [0.612127] 'Chapter Zero' '00:08:39.1301587'
Recognized [0.798621] 'Chapter Nine' '00:08:44.2784580'
Recognized [0.835795] 'Chapter Six' '00:08:48.4489795'
Recognized [0.766998] 'Chapter Three' '00:08:53.1682539'
Recognized [0.771680] 'Chapter One' '00:08:57.6081632'
Recognized [0.933043] 'Chapter Four' '00:09:01.3496598'
Recognized [0.766897] 'Chapter Three' '00:09:05.1111111'
Recognized [0.816078] 'Chapter Nine' '00:09:09.4911564'
Recognized [0.746574] 'Chapter Three' '00:09:15.4276643'
Recognized [0.942246] 'Chapter Three' '00:09:19.4585034'
Recognized [0.923526] 'Chapter One' '00:09:24.0480725'
Recognized [0.673100] 'Chapter Zero' '00:09:28.7972789'
Recognized [0.924188] 'Chapter Zero' '00:09:33.5564625'
Recognized [0.862414] 'Chapter Five' '00:09:39.6226757'
Recognized [0.685554] 'Chapter Five' '00:09:56.3446712'
Recognized [0.885203] 'Chapter Seven' '00:10:01.4131519'
Recognized [0.768674] 'Chapter Four' '00:10:08.5668934'
Recognized [0.708105] 'Chapter Four' '00:10:18.1850340'
Recognized [0.811211] 'Chapter Six' '00:10:23.8022675'
Recognized [0.904822] 'Chapter One' '00:10:28.8607709'
Recognized [0.760712] 'Chapter One' '00:10:33.2208616'
Recognized [0.847518] 'Chapter Seven' '00:10:41.3823129'
Recognized [0.922872] 'Chapter Seven' '00:10:47.3188208'
Recognized [0.748338] 'Chapter Seven' '00:10:52.1777777'
Recognized [0.754150] 'Chapter Seven' '00:10:57.1764172'
Recognized [0.779514] 'Chapter Seven' '00:11:02.0353741'
Recognized [0.898698] 'Chapter Zero' '00:11:06.7247165'
Recognized [0.678718] 'Chapter Four' '00:11:12.8807256'
Recognized [0.910037] 'Chapter Three' '00:11:17.5002267'
Recognized [0.676493] 'Chapter Seven' '00:11:22.8580498'
Recognized [0.847810] 'Chapter Zero' '00:11:33.4439909'
Recognized [0.852185] 'Chapter Three' '00:11:37.6943310'
Recognized [0.869880] 'Chapter Seven' '00:11:42.1242630'
Recognized [0.657032] 'Chapter Eight' '00:11:47.7115646'
Recognized [0.610273] 'Chapter Zero' '00:11:52.4807256'
Recognized [0.697250] 'Chapter Five' '00:11:57.4195011'
Recognized [0.829167] 'Chapter Three' '00:12:02.5278911'
Recognized [0.833108] 'Chapter Six' '00:12:08.9233560'
Recognized [0.911786] 'Chapter Four' '00:12:13.8222222'
Recognized [0.688799] 'Chapter Seven' '00:12:17.9229024'
Recognized [0.915079] 'Chapter One' '00:12:22.9714285'
Recognized [0.661166] 'Chapter Seven' '00:12:27.7804988'
Recognized [0.846345] 'Chapter Seven' '00:12:39.5238095'
Recognized [0.859780] 'Chapter Six' '00:12:44.7619047'
Recognized [0.928802] 'Chapter Seven' '00:12:50.6086167'
Recognized [0.684971] 'Chapter Zero' '00:12:55.7868480'
Recognized [0.670632] 'Chapter Zero' '00:13:00.2566893'
Recognized [0.640998] 'Chapter One' '00:13:05.4748299'
Recognized [0.698716] 'Chapter Zero' '00:13:10.5732426'
Recognized [0.823498] 'Chapter Six' '00:13:15.8412698'
Recognized [0.868738] 'Chapter Four' '00:13:21.8176870'
Recognized [0.710738] 'Chapter Four' '00:13:27.1256235'
Recognized [0.913386] 'Chapter One' '00:13:34.3990929'
Recognized [0.743341] 'Chapter Five' '00:13:37.9809523'
Recognized [0.890146] 'Chapter Zero' '00:13:42.9197278'
Recognized [0.675870] 'Chapter Nine' '00:13:47.6090702'
Recognized [0.928774] 'Chapter Seven' '00:13:51.2108843'
Recognized [0.880698] 'Chapter Seven' '00:13:57.2970521'
Recognized [0.837221] 'Chapter Seven' '00:14:04.0317460'
Recognized [0.873171] 'Chapter Five' '00:14:09.9083900'
Recognized [0.861104] 'Chapter Two' '00:14:13.9092970'
Recognized [0.735503] 'Chapter Five' '00:14:21.0630385'
Recognized [0.914970] 'Chapter Two' '00:14:25.7723356'
Recognized [0.737040] 'Chapter Three' '00:14:31.2000000'
Recognized [0.832584] 'Chapter Seven' '00:14:37.3560090'
Recognized [0.770115] 'Chapter Two' '00:14:42.3746031'
Recognized [0.851399] 'Chapter Six' '00:14:48.6403628'
Recognized [0.892431] 'Chapter Five' '00:14:52.8108843'
Recognized [0.767154] 'Chapter Three' '00:14:57.6598639'
Recognized [0.903126] 'Chapter One' '00:15:01.9700680'
Recognized [0.927501] 'Chapter Eight' '00:15:07.5374149'
Recognized [0.775459] 'Chapter Three' '00:15:11.7378684'
Recognized [0.855747] 'Chapter Five' '00:15:17.1156462'
Recognized [0.906138] 'Chapter Six' '00:15:22.1342403'
Recognized [0.821299] 'Chapter Nine' '00:15:26.9832199'
Recognized [0.929456] 'Chapter Five' '00:15:32.4607709'
Recognized [0.874424] 'Chapter Seven' '00:15:36.5814058'
Recognized [0.620315] 'Chapter Seven' '00:15:42.2385487'
Recognized [0.903528] 'Chapter Zero' '00:15:47.5464852'
Recognized [0.795379] 'Chapter Six' '00:15:51.7968253'
Recognized [0.622142] 'Chapter One' '00:15:56.4761904'
Recognized [0.811500] 'Chapter Three' '00:16:01.8839002'
Recognized [0.898530] 'Chapter Six' '00:16:07.1519274'
Recognized [0.942042] 'Chapter Seven' '00:16:12.1306122'
Recognized [0.920825] 'Chapter Nine' '00:16:18.9251700'
Recognized [0.886504] 'Chapter One' '00:16:22.7963718'
Recognized [0.784477] 'Chapter Three' '00:16:28.4734693'
Recognized [0.850595] 'Chapter Eight' '00:16:37.1138321'
Recognized [0.634020] 'Chapter Eight' '00:16:41.6136054'
Recognized [0.648564] 'Chapter Zero' '00:16:46.7619047'
Recognized [0.716741] 'Chapter One' '00:16:51.5510204'
Recognized [0.844194] 'Chapter Nine' '00:16:56.8988662'
Recognized [0.823612] 'Chapter Zero' '00:17:09.1709750'
Recognized [0.804577] 'Chapter Seven' '00:17:14.2494331'
Recognized [0.917299] 'Chapter Five' '00:17:21.9918367'
Recognized [0.903172] 'Chapter Five' '00:17:27.5691609'
Recognized [0.924532] 'Chapter Five' '00:17:32.5977324'
Recognized [0.877819] 'Chapter Zero' '00:17:39.3424036'
Recognized [0.945488] 'Chapter Three' '00:17:46.0870748'
Recognized [0.920278] 'Chapter Zero' '00:17:51.6544217'
Recognized [0.715859] 'Chapter Seven' '00:17:56.0943310'
Recognized [0.891746] 'Chapter Zero' '00:18:01.1428571'
Recognized [0.728244] 'Chapter Zero' '00:18:05.9918367'
Recognized [0.795327] 'Chapter Four' '00:18:11.1501133'
Recognized [0.772625] 'Chapter Seven' '00:18:15.3106575'
Recognized [0.914410] 'Chapter One' '00:18:19.3913832'
Recognized [0.841603] 'Chapter Five' '00:18:23.3723356'
Recognized [0.885254] 'Chapter Eight' '00:18:30.6158730'
Recognized [0.775661] 'Chapter Four' '00:18:41.5210884'
Recognized [0.638765] 'Chapter Zero' '00:18:46.7591836'
Recognized [0.804591] 'Chapter Zero' '00:18:51.9274376'
Recognized [0.906230] 'Chapter Zero' '00:18:57.2453514'
Recognized [0.628863] 'Chapter Six' '00:19:01.3560090'
Recognized [0.694696] 'Chapter Two' '00:19:07.1029478'
Recognized [0.929444] 'Chapter Six' '00:19:11.8721088'
Recognized [0.665487] 'Chapter Eight' '00:19:22.0888888'
Recognized [0.844721] 'Chapter Zero' '00:19:26.4190476'
Recognized [0.726267] 'Chapter Nine' '00:19:37.9727891'
Recognized [0.772948] 'Chapter Eight' '00:19:42.5024943'
Recognized [0.884429] 'Chapter Seven' '00:19:46.8126984'
Recognized [0.914303] 'Chapter Six' '00:19:51.4820861'
Recognized [0.810541] 'Chapter Seven' '00:20:01.0802721'
Recognized [0.831496] 'Chapter Seven' '00:20:06.5777777'
Recognized [0.760354] 'Chapter Four' '00:20:11.2172335'
Recognized [0.765746] 'Chapter One' '00:20:16.0063492'
Recognized [0.828661] 'Chapter Eight' '00:20:19.8775510'
Recognized [0.933618] 'Chapter Eight' '00:20:25.4448979'
Recognized [0.860785] 'Chapter One' '00:20:31.5011337'
Recognized [0.786197] 'Chapter Seven' '00:20:35.3424036'
Recognized [0.920584] 'Chapter Seven' '00:20:39.8621315'
Recognized [0.805903] 'Chapter Three' '00:20:45.9283446'
Recognized [0.933252] 'Chapter Four' '00:20:50.2784580'
Recognized [0.796793] 'Chapter Three' '00:20:55.6562358'
Recognized [0.883440] 'Chapter Seven' '00:21:13.7351473'
Recognized [0.901213] 'Chapter Nine' '00:21:18.3945578'
Recognized [0.710592] 'Chapter Seven' '00:21:23.3333333'
Recognized [0.737947] 'Chapter Three' '00:21:41.3024943'
Recognized [0.917786] 'Chapter Eight' '00:21:45.0539682'
Recognized [0.816457] 'Chapter Four' '00:21:49.4340136'
Recognized [0.904251] 'Chapter Nine' '00:21:54.8816326'
Recognized [0.827680] 'Chapter Zero' '00:22:06.0761904'
Recognized [0.839630] 'Chapter One' '00:22:10.6956916'
Recognized [0.914018] 'Chapter One' '00:22:16.6421768'
Recognized [0.715777] 'Chapter Seven' '00:22:21.4412698'
Recognized [0.733097] 'Chapter Zero' '00:22:27.0585034'
Recognized [0.710224] 'Chapter Three' '00:22:31.2290249'
Recognized [0.872167] 'Chapter Nine' '00:22:35.7886621'
Recognized [0.775699] 'Chapter Zero' '00:22:43.5809523'
Recognized [0.876188] 'Chapter Nine' '00:22:54.5560090'
Recognized [0.915597] 'Chapter Zero' '00:23:06.3791383'
Recognized [0.708735] 'Chapter Five' '00:23:12.8544217'
Recognized [0.946594] 'Chapter Five' '00:23:19.1401360'
Recognized [0.645959] 'Chapter One' '00:23:23.4204081'
Recognized [0.919772] 'Chapter Zero' '00:23:32.5995464'
Recognized [0.779969] 'Chapter Three' '00:23:36.7301587'
Recognized [0.933196] 'Chapter Three' '00:23:41.8984126'
Recognized [0.947368] 'Chapter One' '00:23:47.3959183'
Recognized [0.909682] 'Chapter One' '00:23:55.5972789'
Recognized [0.810724] 'Chapter One' '00:24:02.2022675'
Recognized [0.950602] 'Chapter Nine' '00:24:08.6077097'
Recognized [0.973474] 'Chapter One' '00:24:14.6439909'
Recognized [0.840169] 'Chapter Six' '00:24:20.5705215'
Recognized [0.853712] 'Chapter Four' '00:24:30.4680272'
Recognized [0.752738] 'Chapter Seven' '00:24:35.3369614'
Recognized [0.908675] 'Chapter One' '00:24:39.7569160'
Recognized [0.915611] 'Chapter Six' '00:24:44.6358276'
Recognized [0.911057] 'Chapter Zero' '00:24:49.2453514'
Recognized [0.717390] 'Chapter Seven' '00:24:53.8748299'
Recognized [0.885464] 'Chapter Zero' '00:24:59.1827664'
Recognized [0.939139] 'Chapter Six' '00:25:05.5882086'
Recognized [0.929132] 'Chapter Nine' '00:25:12.6521541'
Recognized [0.789475] 'Chapter One' '00:25:18.2195011'
Recognized [0.866239] 'Chapter Five' '00:25:23.8666666'
Recognized [0.742766] 'Chapter One' '00:25:28.7555555'
Recognized [0.722613] 'Chapter Six' '00:25:37.6154195'
Recognized [0.792798] 'Chapter One' '00:25:42.5442176'
Recognized [0.663454] 'Chapter Five' '00:25:47.7523809'
Recognized [0.681175] 'Chapter Seven' '00:25:52.6312925'
Recognized [0.941754] 'Chapter Six' '00:26:04.5043083'
Recognized [0.926863] 'Chapter Nine' '00:26:13.4539682'
Recognized [0.780279] 'Chapter Seven' '00:26:17.2553287'
Recognized [0.889462] 'Chapter Nine' '00:26:22.1442176'
Recognized [0.710386] 'Chapter Zero' '00:26:27.7714285'
Recognized [0.830702] 'Chapter Six' '00:26:43.4458049'
Recognized [0.905110] 'Chapter Nine' '00:26:47.6063492'
Recognized [0.602287] 'Chapter One' '00:26:56.8553287'
Recognized [0.681035] 'Chapter Five' '00:27:01.1755102'
Recognized [0.940345] 'Chapter One' '00:27:05.2761904'
Recognized [0.676020] 'Chapter Five' '00:27:11.8213151'
Recognized [0.613714] 'Chapter Seven' '00:27:16.4807256'
Recognized [0.750310] 'Chapter One' '00:27:21.4993197'
Recognized [0.723749] 'Chapter Seven' '00:27:28.5433106'
Recognized [0.898270] 'Chapter One' '00:27:33.8213151'
Recognized [0.894368] 'Chapter Three' '00:27:41.6235827'
Recognized [0.665457] 'Chapter Six' '00:27:46.2031746'
Recognized [0.788669] 'Chapter Two' '00:27:51.1918367'
Recognized [0.847941] 'Chapter Four' '00:28:02.2167800'
Recognized [0.808592] 'Chapter Seven' '00:28:06.1478458'
Recognized [0.924393] 'Chapter Zero' '00:28:11.3360544'
Recognized [0.772634] 'Chapter Six' '00:28:19.4875283'
Recognized [0.890229] 'Chapter Four' '00:28:24.6956916'
Recognized [0.718494] 'Chapter Seven' '00:28:28.8263038'
Recognized [0.808105] 'Chapter Three' '00:28:33.3560090'
Recognized [0.712118] 'Chapter Zero' '00:28:37.8458049'
Recognized [0.944408] 'Chapter Six' '00:28:42.6748299'
Recognized [0.889619] 'Chapter Seven' '00:28:48.5814058'
Recognized [0.835841] 'Chapter One' '00:28:54.0190476'
Recognized [0.893045] 'Chapter Eight' '00:28:58.7682539'
Recognized [0.844410] 'Chapter Five' '00:29:09.6335600'
Recognized [0.784058] 'Chapter One' '00:29:14.3827664'
Recognized [0.617414] 'Chapter Nine' '00:29:19.3814058'
Recognized [0.697014] 'Chapter One' '00:29:28.9496598'
Recognized [0.645328] 'Chapter Seven' '00:29:33.5791383'
Recognized [0.918602] 'Chapter One' '00:29:37.7795918'
Recognized [0.606370] 'Chapter Seven' '00:29:43.4666666'
Recognized [0.927960] 'Chapter One' '00:29:59.3904761'
Recognized [0.861881] 'Chapter Seven' '00:30:09.1183673'
Recognized [0.802617] 'Chapter Zero' '00:30:14.6258503'
Recognized [0.890691] 'Chapter One' '00:30:19.8240362'
Recognized [0.898630] 'Chapter Seven' '00:30:24.9523809'
Recognized [0.769664] 'Chapter Nine' '00:30:29.8213151'
Recognized [0.898534] 'Chapter Zero' '00:30:33.7623582'
Recognized [0.934961] 'Chapter One' '00:30:44.7773242'
Recognized [0.625531] 'Chapter Three' '00:30:52.8888888'
Recognized [0.888719] 'Chapter Four' '00:30:59.1247165'
Recognized [0.873550] 'Chapter One' '00:31:03.2453514'
Recognized [0.880971] 'Chapter One' '00:31:07.6453514'
Recognized [0.829944] 'Chapter Zero' '00:31:11.5963718'
Recognized [0.819353] 'Chapter One' '00:31:28.6077097'
Recognized [0.935669] 'Chapter One' '00:31:33.3768707'
Recognized [0.875531] 'Chapter Eight' '00:31:37.6671201'
Recognized [0.817026] 'Chapter Three' '00:31:41.6580498'
Recognized [0.893548] 'Chapter Zero' '00:31:46.3174603'
Recognized [0.662632] 'Chapter One' '00:31:51.0866213'
Recognized [0.845510] 'Chapter One' '00:31:56.2648526'
Recognized [0.740274] 'Chapter One' '00:32:01.8621315'
Recognized [0.897936] 'Chapter Three' '00:32:06.8009070'
Recognized [0.919574] 'Chapter Eight' '00:32:11.3106575'
Recognized [0.700058] 'Chapter Zero' '00:32:15.3614512'
Recognized [0.898780] 'Chapter Nine' '00:32:20.2902494'
Recognized [0.864019] 'Chapter Zero' '00:32:25.8176870'
Recognized [0.795984] 'Chapter One' '00:32:34.6176870'
Recognized [0.853801] 'Chapter Nine' '00:32:39.6263038'
Recognized [0.703184] 'Chapter Seven' '00:32:50.0526077'
Recognized [0.829835] 'Chapter Nine' '00:32:55.7496598'
Recognized [0.737604] 'Chapter Three' '00:33:00.1995464'
Recognized [0.677041] 'Chapter Seven' '00:33:04.9287981'
Recognized [0.873017] 'Chapter Three' '00:33:09.9274376'
Recognized [0.877553] 'Chapter Seven' '00:33:14.9260770'
Recognized [0.946166] 'Chapter Seven' '00:33:20.7628117'
Recognized [0.804708] 'Chapter One' '00:33:26.0208616'
Recognized [0.901493] 'Chapter Zero' '00:33:43.4312925'
Recognized [0.824169] 'Chapter Zero' '00:33:51.1936507'
Recognized [0.871196] 'Chapter Seven' '00:33:57.0204081'
Recognized [0.769965] 'Chapter Zero' '00:34:01.5201814'
Recognized [0.882437] 'Chapter Three' '00:34:11.3777777'
Recognized [0.945319] 'Chapter Nine' '00:34:16.7954648'
Recognized [0.823991] 'Chapter Seven' '00:34:27.6907029'
Recognized [0.849985] 'Chapter Four' '00:34:33.1782312'
Recognized [0.786698] 'Chapter One' '00:34:38.8952380'
Recognized [0.896799] 'Chapter Zero' '00:34:43.3151927'
Recognized [0.928113] 'Chapter One' '00:34:48.5333333'
Recognized [0.940975] 'Chapter Three' '00:34:52.5043083'
Recognized [0.902565] 'Chapter Zero' '00:34:58.1315192'
Recognized [0.894258] 'Chapter One' '00:35:02.7709750'
Recognized [0.894185] 'Chapter Seven' '00:35:07.7995464'
Recognized [0.939630] 'Chapter One' '00:35:13.1573696'
Recognized [0.896020] 'Chapter Seven' '00:35:18.2158730'
Recognized [0.783186] 'Chapter One' '00:35:23.8630385'
Recognized [0.927390] 'Chapter One' '00:35:28.0235827'
Recognized [0.821132] 'Chapter Seven' '00:35:33.8902494'
Recognized [0.921723] 'Chapter Three' '00:35:38.2303854'
Recognized [0.625486] 'Chapter Seven' '00:35:42.3210884'
Recognized [0.927362] 'Chapter Five' '00:35:47.0902494'
Recognized [0.813336] 'Chapter Five' '00:35:51.7596371'
Recognized [0.850605] 'Chapter Nine' '00:35:56.7083900'
Recognized [0.879817] 'Chapter Nine' '00:36:00.6893424'
Recognized [0.767620] 'Chapter Zero' '00:36:04.6303854'
Recognized [0.751701] 'Chapter Seven' '00:36:10.9360544'
Recognized [0.924697] 'Chapter Nine' '00:36:16.0544217'
Recognized [0.910720] 'Chapter Eight' '00:36:21.0730158'
Recognized [0.942171] 'Chapter One' '00:36:24.8145124'
Recognized [0.640849] 'Chapter One' '00:36:29.2544217'
Recognized [0.788366] 'Chapter Three' '00:36:35.2607709'
Recognized [0.921676] 'Chapter One' '00:36:39.0721088'
Recognized [0.903096] 'Chapter Seven' '00:36:45.0984126'
Recognized [0.861046] 'Chapter One' '00:36:49.3687074'
Recognized [0.923926] 'Chapter Eight' '00:36:56.0634920'
Recognized [0.848739] 'Chapter Three' '00:36:59.9446712'
Recognized [0.613532] 'Chapter Four' '00:37:05.0231292'
Recognized [0.748194] 'Chapter Seven' '00:37:10.4507936'
Recognized [0.867573] 'Chapter Nine' '00:37:16.2476190'
Recognized [0.893390] 'Chapter Three' '00:37:25.7460317'
Recognized [0.855499] 'Chapter Nine' '00:37:34.4263038'
Recognized [0.830073] 'Chapter Zero' '00:37:41.5201814'
Recognized [0.673731] 'Chapter Zero' '00:37:49.5419501'
Recognized [0.900220] 'Chapter One' '00:37:55.7678004'
Recognized [0.720431] 'Chapter Nine' '00:38:02.3727891'
Recognized [0.799679] 'Chapter Nine' '00:38:07.6707482'
Recognized [0.750786] 'Chapter Zero' '00:38:13.0385487'
Recognized [0.798787] 'Chapter Zero' '00:38:17.3986394'
Recognized [0.861327] 'Chapter Seven' '00:38:23.8739229'
Recognized [0.882927] 'Chapter Seven' '00:38:28.4435374'
Recognized [0.717402] 'Chapter One' '00:38:33.3424036'
Recognized [0.927742] 'Chapter One' '00:38:38.2811791'
Recognized [0.781828] 'Chapter Seven' '00:38:48.2185941'
Recognized [0.925028] 'Chapter Nine' '00:38:53.2272108'
Recognized [0.602354] 'Chapter Six' '00:38:57.7668934'
Recognized [0.836671] 'Chapter Seven' '00:39:03.1746031'
Recognized [0.943111] 'Chapter Zero' '00:39:08.7319727'
Recognized [0.912576] 'Chapter Zero' '00:39:12.9224489'
Recognized [0.926495] 'Chapter Zero' '00:39:17.4521541'
Recognized [0.916129] 'Chapter Seven' '00:39:23.3287981'
Recognized [0.934193] 'Chapter Two' '00:39:29.7442176'
Recognized [0.942777] 'Chapter Nine' '00:39:34.3637188'
Recognized [0.941664] 'Chapter Eight' '00:39:39.1727891'
```

I'm not sure how I would be able to optimize the speech recognition to be able to give me meaningful results to parse through.

Comment: System.Speech is not very effective for keyword spotting with grammar and confidence threshold. It is better to use specialized library for spotting or consider full transcription which will be much more more accurate than simple spotting.

Comment: Is there another framework that does a better job at keyword spotting?

Comment: I had decent success with Vosk: https://www.blisshq.com/music-library-management-blog/2021/01/22/splitting-audiobooks-chapters-ai/